# tinyMCE does not load

Tags: tinymce, html-editor

i have been trying very hard to make tinyMCE work on my page. even a simple example like the below is not working.. i have tried in all the browsers..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>index page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" >
    </script>
        <script
        type = "text/javascript" > 
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "simple",
            plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template"
        });
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="somePage.php">
        <textarea name="textAreaContent" style="width:100%"> 
    This is some content that will be editable with TinyMCE.
    </textarea>
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

i have checked the link for javascript and tat is perfect. 
can some one pls help me...

Comment: What means "not working"? TinyMCE doesn't initialize? You have just textarea with text in it? Or it initializes not the way you think it should? Or you get errors? I've tested your example with versions 3.3.9 and 3.4.7 (Firefox 9, IE 8) and everything was OK. Which version do you use?

Comment: try initializing without any plugins (plugins:'',)  to see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, i just tested with version 3.4.7,
look for missing plugins in: javascripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins

Comment: i have the plugins folder. i also tried removing all the plugins. i just tried     <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js" >
   </script >
   <script
   type = "text/javascript" > 
   tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "simple"
    });
  </script> and even this did not work